# How can I stop this mysqli extension class from stopping executing on a failed 'real_connect'?

Tags: php, mysqli

So the following code is in its infantile stages, and has a long way to go - but I am working on a database platform that is aware of multiple databases ( slaves, etc ), that is meant to attempt to open a connection to one, and upon failure, continue on to another. The relevant methods in the 'DatabaseConnection' class are as follows:

```
class DatabaseConnection extends mysqli
{
    public function __construct($ConnectAutomatically=false,$Name="database",$Host="127.0.0.1",$Username="root",$Password="",$Catalog="",$Port=3306)
    {
        $this->CurrentHost = $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'];           

        $this->Name = $Name;
        $this->Host = $Host;
        $this->Username = $Username;
        $this->Password = $Password;
        $this->Port = $Port;
        $this->Catalog = $Catalog;

        if( $ConnectAutomatically )
            parent::__construct($this->Host, $this->Username, $this->Password, $this->Catalog, $this->Port);
        else
            parent::init();

        return;
    }

    public function Open()
    {
        try
        {
            if(!parent::real_connect($this->Host,$this->Username,$this->Password,$this->Catalog,$this->Port))
            {
                return false;
            }
            else
                return true;
        }
        catch( Exception $e )
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

The idea is that the database could be queried at any time, without having been initialized - therefore, the Query method checks for connectivity, and upon a lack thereof, runs the 'Open' method.

I have intentionally put a bad character in the password to force it to fail to connect, to see if it would connect to the second server in the list - but on the 'parent::real_connect' line, I am getting the obvious response that I cannot connect due to an invalid password.

I am wondering if there is a different approach I can take in this 'Open' method to NOT stop execution upon failure in the real_connect operation. I've taken a few swings at this and come up short, so I had to ask. It seems from my perspective that mysqli won't allow program execution to continue if the connect fails...

I have custom error catching already in place, which seems to catch the fault - but without interpreting the error and re-executing the DatabaseHandler connect method with the next in the list from Within my error handler, I don't see many other approaches at the moment.

I'll be glad to share more if need be.

Comment: Is `Open` supposed to try the next database in the list, or is this done by the code that calls `Open`? If `Open` does it, where does it get the list from?

Comment: The 'parent' class 'DatabaseHandler' stores a list of 'DatabaseConnection's that it 'Open's on demand.

Comment: I should go on to say that I am fairly sure my logic in that respect is working; as long as I can return false from THIS Open method - which never occurs. It simply faults out on the 'real_connect' and dies.

Comment: I don't see how it can fault out with the error handler in place. Put `echo` statements before each of the `return` statements and see which block is actually being executed.

Comment: The only other option I see here is re-routing error handling to my 'DatabaseHandler.Connect' method until I have established a connection, and then set it back to my standard ErrorHandler... But that seems cumbersome.

Comment: *on the 'parent::real_connect' line, I am getting the obvious response* - This isn't actually obvious; where does this error come from, e.g., is it a PHP warning? I don't see a mechanism to communicate the error (you might include the exact message text as well).

Comment: Your last comment, @Barmar, did spark something... Apparently the real_connect IS being called twice; for reasons I need to look into - but the error is a mysql error that comes up inside my error handler after it has retrieved it - which could mean it is an exception, a runtime error, or some other error... I've taken precautions to be able to catch every error PHP can throw... But the exact message is: 'mysqli::real_connect(): (28000/1045): Access denied for user 'root'@'SG5514' (using password: YES)'

Comment: Which is intentional... I mentioned that I gave it a bad password on purpose. I want to know why execution stops completely when MySQL can't connect - but that may be something to take up with my error handler, too...

Comment: If it's any help, this is coming back as a 'runtime error' rather than an exception or fatal error - which refers to anything that 'set_error_handler' would catch; so I can effectively narrow down what Type of error I am ending up with - the question is why; if not fatal or exception, is it stopping execution.

Comment: FURTHERMore... It looks like I'm getting Two errors here - first a 'runtime error' and then at the very end, a 'Fatal Error'. Perhaps this is where I should be looking.